# NetworkX Key Error when writing GML file

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, networkx, graphml

I am getting the following error message when attempting to write GML file after merging two graphs using compose():

```
NetworkXError: 'user_id' is not a valid key
```

The background is that I import two GML files using:

```
g = nx.read_gml(file_path + "test_graph_1.gml")
h = nx.read_gml(file_path + "test_graph_2.gml")
```

Each node (in both GML files) file is structured thus:

```
node [
id 9
user_id "1663413990"
file "wingsscotland.dat"
label "brian_bilston"
image "/Users/ian/development/gtf/gtf/img/1663413990.jpg"
type "friends"
statuses 21085
friends 737
followers 53425
listed 550
ffr 72.4898
lfr 0.1029
shape "triangle-up"
]
```

After importing each file, I can check all the node attributes, see that nodes are unique within each graph.

I also see that NetworkX by default discards the 'id' field, und uses the 'label' as the identifier of the node. It retains the user_id attribute (which happens to be a Twitter user_id and suits my purposes well).

Running

```
list(f.nodes(data=True))
```

I can see that the data for the node above is:

```
('brian_bilston',
{'ffr': 72.4898,
'file': 'wingsscotland.dat',
'followers': 53425,
'friends': 737,
'image': '/Users/ian/development/gtf/gtf/img/1663413990.jpg',
'lfr': 0.1029,
'listed': 550,
'shape': 'triangle-up',
'statuses': 21085,
'type': 'friends',
'user_id': '1663413990'})
```

There is (in this test case) one common node shared by Graph g and Graph h, - the one shown above. All others are unique by user_id and label.

I then merge the two graphs using:

```
f = nx.compose(g,h)
```

This works ok.

I then go to write out a new GML from the graph, f, using:

```
nx.write_gml(f, file_path + "one_plus_two.gml")
```

At this point I get the error, above:

```
  NetworkXError: 'user_id' is not a valid key
```

I have checked the uniqueness of all user_id's (in case I had duplicated one):

```
uid = nx.get_node_attributes(f,'user_id')
print(uid)
```

Which outputs:

```
{'brian_bilston': '1663413990', 
'ICMResearch': '100', 
'justcswilliams': '200', 
'MissBabington': '300', 
'ProBirdRights': '400', 
'FredSmith': '247775851', 
'JasWatt': '160952087', 
'Angela_Lewis': '2316946782', 
'Fuzzpig54': '130136162', 
'SonnyRussel': '828881340', 
'JohnBird': '448476934', 
'AngusMcAngus': '19785044'}
```

(formatted for readability).

So, all user_id's are unique, as far as I can tell.

So, if it is not a question of uniqueness of keys, what is the error telling me?

I've exhausted my thinking on this!

Any pointers, please, would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I posted this as an issue on the NextworkX GitHub repo, where it was answered by an admin.

See: https://github.com/networkx/networkx/issues/3100

I have posted his answer below:

> Yes -- this is a known issue: see [#2131](https://github.com/networkx/networkx/issues/2131)
>
> The GML spec doesn't allow underscores in attribute names. We allow
>   reading .gml files that don't correspond to the official GML spec. But
>   we write only items that follow the spec. You should convert your
>   attribute names to not include the underscore.
>
> ```
> for n in G:
>     G.node[n]['userid'] = G.node[n]['user_id']
>     del G.node[n]['user_id']
> ```
>
> We should also add to the documentation a note about this.